# Is there any way to get all custom posts and all custom terms with it's meta in few queries?

Tags: query, post-meta, meta-query, cache, optimization

I'm developing a website with a record for me query count. It has 720 Query for the main page. I want to reduce it.

The main page structure is like this:

- ~10 Custom Taxonomy Term
- Each Term has a query for name, slug, cover (from the `term_meta table`)
- Each Term has 3 Custom Post Type
- Each Post from these Custom Post Type query for ~4 Meta fields and thumbnail

I tried transient cache tech, but it didn't help me in the right measure.

Can I somehow reduce query amount by making a few queries to bring all data to arrays and manipulate with data using these arrays?

Comment: What is the code you're actually using to query all this stuff? Are you querying the 10 taxonomy terms separately? Or using `get_terms()` to get them all at once? What about the meta? Normally WordPress gets all meta values for each term or post in a single query too. And what about the posts within the terms?

Comment: @JacobPeattie I get all terms with get_terms(). In foreach of get_terms() array I making get_term_meta() and get_option(). Next, for each term I'm making WP_Query() for each post type. For each post I'm making get_the_title(), get_the_id(), get_post_meta() and etc. I know that some data should be cached with the core, but 720 Query make this non-sense. 720 Queries showing the [Query monitor plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/)